# How do I find the equivalent resistance between positions A,B, C and D in this diagram?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, home-experiment

So I am a prelab assignment where I need to calculate the equivalent resistance between two assigned points. Here is my attempt so far:

[image]

The thing that is troubling me is the point C and D, where the resistance R4 lies. I don't understand how to take in account this resistance in the circuit: Is it excluded from the circuit since no current pass through it? I'm really not sure about this.

Can someone explain for me what happens for each point (ex: A and B, A and C, etc.)

I've made an attempt at doing it but I am totally confused because I never saw a circuit where the resistance is out of the loop.

Comment: Yes, for some reason, this tends to confuse the hell out of students :)

Comment: Remember $R_{\rm eq}=\frac{V}{I}$. Consider applying a voltage between C&D and try computing the current from C to D directly. Or inject a current at C and extract it at D- either way works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it excluded from the circuit since no current pass through it? I'm
>   really not sure about this.

As drawn, there is no source and so the current is *zero* through *all resistors*.

This is a resistor *network* and the question is asking, in effect, for you to *imagine* placing the leads of an ohmmeter across, e.g., nodes A & B (or A & D etc.) and calculating what the ohmmeter will display.

A physical ohmmeter can be conceptualized as a voltage source in series with an ammeter.  The voltage source *drives* the resistor network and there is a resulting current.  The ammeter measures the resulting current and the equivalent resistance is, by Ohm's law, just the voltage of the source divided by the current through the ammeter (the ammeter reading can then be scaled with units of ohms).

So, to *visualize* this process, draw a (unit) voltage source in series with an ammeter and then connect this series combination across nodes A & D.  Now *see* that the resistor $R_4$ *is* in circuit and that there is a current through it and thus, its resistance is a factor in the equivalent resistance between nodes A & D.

On the other hand, if you connect across nodes A & B, the resistor $R_4$ is 'dangling', i.e., one end is not connected to anything and so, there is no current through it - it is *out* of circuit and thus, is not a factor in the equivalent resistance between nodes A & B.

Answer (score -1):

You are correct. If no current flows through a resistor you do not include it in the calculation.

When the electrodes are placed at C(+) and D(-) the current takes all possible routes from C to D without returning to C before it reaches D. So no current flows around the loop ABC in this case.

Comment: So, is the equivalent resistance between C and D just R4?

Comment: Sorry we don't check your work. We only explain the physics. Is there some reason why you are still uncertain?

Comment: Why the down-vote? (whoever it was)